# How to use my class within another class in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Yes, this is a really bad question, probably one that any half decent VB.NET programmer should know. Well, I am new to VB.NET, so I need a little help.

I have created a windows forms class along side another one, and its code is this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form2

    Protected m_BlankValid As Boolean = True
    Protected m_ReturnText As String = ""

    Public Overloads Function ShowDialog( _
      ByVal TitleText As String, _
      ByVal PromptText As String, _
      ByVal DefaultText As String, _
      ByRef EnteredText As String, _
      ByVal BlankValid As Boolean) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult
        m_BlankValid = BlankValid
        Me.PromptLabel.Text = PromptText
        Me.Text = TitleText
        Me.Txt_TextEntry.Text = DefaultText
        Me.ShowDialog()
        EnteredText = m_ReturnText
        Return Me.DialogResult
    End Function

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Me.Txt_TextEntry.Text = "" Then
            Me.OK_Btn.Enabled = m_BlankValid
        Else
            Me.OK_Btn.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        m_ReturnText = Me.Txt_TextEntry.Text
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cancel_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        m_ReturnText = ""
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Obviously, I have some graphics on my Design.

To call my class, I would like to use the following code:

```
Dim TextReturned As String = ""
Dim a As New InputBox
If a.ShowDialog("The Title", "The Prompt", "Default", TextReturned, False) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
    ' Cancel Pressed
    Beep()
Else
    '
End If
```

My error is that Type 'InputBox' is not defined. How can I make it such that it is defined?

Thanks,

Odinulf

Comment: Not sure where you got the word InputBox from? Look at your class at the top, you've called it "Form2".  Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code above is copy/pasted from your actual code, your class is named `Form2` not `InputBox`.  Change the class declaration on your custom form to `Public Class InputBox`

If your the snippets above just have a typo, that may change things, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads:

`Dim a As New InputBox`

but the class is defined as:

`Public Class Form2`

Meaning that your code should read:

`Dim as New Form2()`

note: alternatively you could rename your class as:
`Public Class Form2`

to

`Public Class InputBox`

Comment: Thanks a ton. I got the code off the internet, and forgot to change the code to fit. Duh.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the code you posted, your "InputBox" is called Form2 (class name). Change that to InputBox and it should work.

Comment: This won't work.  InputBox is already used as a method name by VB.NET.  It would need to be changed to something else.

Answer (score -1):

`InputBox` is not a type or class, it's a method.  For example...

`InputBox("The Title", "The prompt") 'and any other parameters you need`

Comment: Yep, should have probably read the entire question instead of the last sentance lol.